# How to configure dynamic app_id programmatically for Google Play game services?

Tags: android, google-play-games

In my project I need to configure `app_id` at runtime, but for now I have found only one way, with Manifest.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Can I do it progammatically? Maybe in nearest releases?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio for you application programming than you can achieve it by declaring you app_id string resource in app Gradle file.

Declare it in:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "<YOUR PACKAGE>"
            .....
            resValue "string" "app_id" getApplicationId()
    }
}
```

and now you'll easily find the string resource R.string.app_id, which is automatically generated for you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is also build-time option. I need it for runtime. Like  GoogleSignIn.setAppId("12345"), that i havent find.